# How can I change Image Source outside a Button Template

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, controltemplate

I create this Button Template :

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RoundedButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Border x:Name="buttonBorder"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
            Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
            Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
            CornerRadius="{Binding ElementName=buttonImage, Path=RenderSize}">
        <Grid>
            <Image x:Name="buttonImage" Source="Images/send.png"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="buttonImage" Property="Opacity" Value="0.8"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="buttonBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And I want to change Image Source in MainWindow.xaml like other attributes.
Example: I can change Background in  MainWindow.xaml because I give ***Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"*** But it doesn't work in Image tag. I would appreciate if you help

Comment: Do not directly use an Image element in the ControlTemplate. Instead, use a ContentPresenter and assign an Image as Content when you create a Button.

Comment: I don't fully understand. Can you show the example